# Is it possible to "customize" the multinomial distribution to your specifications?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, multinomial-coefficients

So according to the multinomial distribution, the probability function $\Pr(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, \dots, X_k = x_k)$ is equal to $\dfrac{n!}{x_1! x_2! \cdots x_k!} \cdot p_1^{x_1}\cdot p_2^{x_2} \cdots p_k^{x_k}$

(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

As it is, this distribution allows for at least one $x_j$ to equal zero. Is there a way to define the multinomial distribution for only $x_j > 0$?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how to distribute the missing $0$'s. One way is to use the ordinary multinomial $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_k)$ for sample size $n-k$, and let 
$$\Pr(Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2, \dots, Y_k=y_k)=\Pr(X_1=y_1-1, X_2=y_2-1,\dots,X_k=y_k-1).$$

This does not look particularly interesting, since it is a simple shift of an ordinary multinomial.

**Added:** Another way of "customizing" is to divide the probabilities $\Pr(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,\dots, X_k=x_k)$, where none of the $x_i$ is $0$, by a number $Q$, where $Q$ is the probability that none of the $x_i$ is $0$. Then we face the issue of calculating $Q$. This is $1$ minus the probability that at least one of the $X_i$ takes on the value $0$.

One can express the probability that none of the $X_i$ is $0$ as a complicated sum. It is not clear that there is a pleasant expression for this sum. But we give an approach using Inclusion/Exclusion that is feasible for small $k$, and that with suitable truncation might give useful approximations for larger $k$.

The probability that $X_i=0$ is $(1-p_i)^n$. Add up over all the $i$. We get our first estimate $\sum_i (1-p_1)^n$.

However, this sum double counts all the instances where $X_i=0$ **and** $X_j=0$ for distinct $i$ and $j$. This probability is $(1-p_i-p_j)^n$. So we find the sum $\sum_{i,j}(1-p_i-p_j)^n$. Subtract this from the first estimate to get the second estimate.

But we have taken away too much, all instances where $X_i=0$, $X_j=0$, and $X_l=0$ for distinct $i,j,l$. So we must add back $\sum_{i,j,l} (1-p_i-p_j-p_l)^n$.

Continuing this way, we find $1-Q$, and therefore $Q$.

Comment: where do the $y's$ come from?

Comment: if it helps, here is a link to a similar question I asked that gives more detail about what i'm looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441470/how-to-calculate-probability-using-multinomial-distribution

Comment: could you possible take a look at my other question (which I put in the comment above) and tell me how to apply this to that...

Comment: thanks, but how do I apply your solution to calculate the probability for no $x_j = 0$ ?

Comment: Ah I see, but to be honest both solutions sort of lead to the same thing right? So based on what you said, is this then a true statement? : $\Pr(X_1 > 0, X_2 > 0, \dots, X_k > 0)$ is equal to $\dfrac{(n-k)!}{(x_1-1)! (x_2-1)! \cdots (x_k-1)!} \cdot p_1^{(x_1-1)}\cdot p_2^{(x_2-1)} \cdots p_k^{(x_k-1)}$

Comment: I understand that Q is different, but for your initial solution, is what I have written in my previous comment correct?

Comment: Thanks for your addition, believe it or not that is what I originally had, and as you mentioned, it is quite a messy some. As a mathematical model, I feel as though your initial though of subtracting 1 from all of the $x_i$ and them subtracting k from n was a more sound statement. Do you agree?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you too much information. What I can tell you though is that both n and k can get fairly large. For example, it would be normal to have n = 800 and k = 7...

Comment: The system does not like very long strings of comments. So I will delete most of mine, suggest you do the same. The Inclusion/Exclusion looks feasible, the main issue is whether it produces an appropriate model. And of course the first answer I gave is *very* feasible.

Comment: how do we know that the $$\Pr(Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2, \dots, Y_k=y_k)=\Pr(X_1=y_1-1, X_2=y_2-1,\dots,X_k=y_k-1).$$ What I mean is how do we know that the distribution of $(X_1,...X_k)$ restricted only to the positive integers is the same distribution for $(X_1=y_1-1,...X_k=y_k-1)$ ?

Comment: It is because there is a natural bijection between ordered $k$-tuples $(y_1,\dots, y_k)$, with the $y_i$ positive and $\sum t_i=n$, and ordered $k$-tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ with the $x_i$ non-negative and $\sum x_i=n-k$.